# Regex include new lines

Tags: php, regex

Current regular expression:

```
"/\[(.*?)\](.+?)\[\/(.*?)\]/"
```

Now when I have the following:

```
[test]textextext[/test]
```

it works just fine but it doesn't find

```
[test]tesxc
tcxvxcv
[/test]
```

How do I fix this? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use `^` and `$` along with multiline mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `/s` flag to make `.` match new lines. For example:

```
/\[(\w+)](.+?)\[\/\1]/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
/\[(.*?)\][^.]+\[\/(.*?)\]/
```

You can test these regex at regexpal.com

Comment: Can you explain what `[^.]+` is supposed to do?  Because I really don't think that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... the `s` flag alone may not be such a good idea, because that would allow:

```
[te
xt]123
456[/tex
t]
```

I think you might want this:

```
"(\[(?>([^\]])*)\](.+?)\[/\1\])s"
```

This uses a few clever tricks:

- Once-only subpattern for the opening tag, prevents possible backtracking explosion
- `[^\]]*` instead of `.*?`, so the once-only thing works better and this is more explicit as to what ends your repeating
- End tag uses `\1` to match the same as the opening tag, assuming you want `[abc]...[/abc]` and not `[abc]...[/def]`
- Use `()` instead of `//` to delimit the regex - parentheses come in pairs so there's no need to escape anything inside (you'll notice I just have `/` in the closing tag of the pattern instead of `\/`), but also this can serve as a handy reminder that the first index in the match array is the entire match.

Comment: There are loads of other characters you can use for the regex delimiter, and almost all of them are preferable to `()` in my opinion.  Most people pick character that are rarely-used and have no special meanings in a regex, like `~~` or `%%`.

Comment: @AlanMoore But if your regex happens to be searching for a literal `~` or `%` then you have to escape it. With parentheses, you *never* have to escape just because of a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `/s` modifier.

**Reference :**

> s (PCRE_DOTALL) If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the
>   pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s
>   modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: I think you mean `/s`.  `\s` is the whitespace shorthand.

Comment: @AlanMoore Well, yes! lol. Thanks for pointing this out. Just fixed it.